# Tecno F9 can't write to a TF card (SD card)

Tags: external-sd, tecno

My Tecno F9 ([About phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwrQo.png)) can read the content of a TF card, but it can't write to the TF card. Even if I tried creating a directory, it won't work.

> [image]
>
> Failed to create folder, unknow error!

I even formatted the TF card, but it's still the same.

When I use a file archiver like RAR, I can write to it, but I can't write to it using the phone file manager.

Comment: For write access to sd-cards you need to grant write permission to each app that should access the sd-card. Usually this can be triggered from within the app, then the files app is displayed you you have to select the root of the sd-card and press OK, then focus gets back to the app and app has write permissions. The whole process is pretty confusing.